# Game automatically quits when opponent guesses drawing

Tags: draw-something

Draw something is automatically quitting on me. I've already uninstalled and reinstalled it which didn't work. I managed to get it to work again after I deleted the player and they also deleted me and we started an entirely new game, but after 4 turns it started quitting automatically again. Has anyone else encountered this problem or can think of another fix I haven't tried that might work? I'm playing on my Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 1):

I had this.  Go to the place where you downloaded the game and look for any updates.  I was able to download the update (eventhough it was set to automatically update) and restart my device and it has been fine ever since.